# VBA: Insert into last cell +1

Tags: vba

I am trying to insert information into a cell next to the total column of a pivot table. I can find the last cell however I am unable to increment the column value by 1. Does anyone know of the correct approach? So ideally the last cell is B30. I would like to increment and insert a value into C30. I would like to be able to do this without having to use

```
Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim LastCol As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        With ws
            Set LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        End With
    LastCol = LastCol + 1
    Cells(LastRow.Row, LastCol.Column).Value = "Test"
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of `.Offset()`?

Comment: I had tried using offset however it would end up capturing cell B1

Comment: `Cells(LastRow, LastCol.Column+1).Value = "test"`? or `Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Offset(0,1).Value = "test"`?

Comment: Damn it I had it the wrong way around! If you want you can submit it as ananswer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [`.Offset(rows, columns)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx) property of Range class

```
Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Offset(0,1).Value = "test"
```